# Using MAMP with NGINX

Tags: nginx, mamp, mamp-pro

I see the latest versions of MAMP include NGINX 1.6.

Can NGINX be used instead of apache, or is it just being used to server cached content. If possibel I'd rather use NGINX directives instead of .htaccess.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[image: Mamp Screenshot]

Looks like you can use NGINX as web-server instead of Apache.

Comment: I'm using MAMP pro... how do I get to this screen?

Comment: This ability available only in basic MAMP version.

Comment: [How do I use nginx in MAMP Pro? : appsolute GmbH - support](https://appsolute.zendesk.com/entries/51943805-How-do-I-use-nginx-in-MAMP-PRO-) - posted there September 2, 2014 - starts with instructions to stop MAMP Pro and start MAMP... lol. Haven't found anything newer so far.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you have this option in MAMP PRO:
[image: choice of web server]

Just keep in mind that NGINX needs a different set of parameters. Just trying to get this working myself.